# Greasemonkey, delete <a> element

Tags: greasemonkey

I have this Greasemonkey script, I originally wanted to get all the `<table>` elements and search through those for  but I couldn't get that to work.  So I tried searching for the `<a>` elements themselves and just hiding them if they contained "http://www.4chanscapepk.t35.com" but its not working either.  What am I missing?

```
var results = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for ( var i=0; i<results.length; i++ ) {
    if (
        results[i].href.indexOf("http://www.unwantedsites.com") == 0 ) {
        results[i].parentNode.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe make the condition a little looser? Maybe instead of:

```
results[i].href.indexOf("http://www.unwantedsites.com") == 0 )
```

do:

```
results[i].href.indexOf("unwantedsites.com") >= 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

try using getAttribute instead of directly accessing the property `href`:

```
if ( results[i].getAttribute("href").indexOf("http://www.unwantedsites.com") == 0 ) {
```

Comment: That didn't work either.

I have all the "Included Pages" set correctly.